make sweetalert html element dynamic via its html method
As anticipated by the title I want to make the html element of sweetalert dynamic.
In particular, I have an array with elements inside it.
My goal is to create as many checkboxes as there are elements in the array.
I tried to use foreach inside the html method that sweetalert provides, but as you can easily see from the reproducible example below I get nothing.


const arr = ['Alex','Jasmine','Andrie','Elton','Susy'];

function test() {
Swal.fire({
    html: 
    arr.forEach(user => {
        `  
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="user" name="user" value="">
            <label for="">User</label><br>
        </div>
        `
    }),
    focusConfirm: false,
  })
}

document.getElementById ("test").addEventListener ("click", test);
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.18.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>



  <button type="button" id="test" class="button">
    Click
  </button>



Can someone help me? Can you tell me where I am going wrong?

id="user" will produce invalid HTML on the second and all subsequent since an an id property MUST be unique in the entire document.  In you method you never append to the document however

@MarkSchultheiss Yes of course, it was just an example.

You should accumulate all those value you return from forEach into a long string of HTML. It's easier to do with reduce.


const arr = ['Alex', 'Jasmine', 'Andrie', 'Elton', 'Susy'];

function test() {
  Swal.fire({
    html: arr.reduce((agg, user, index) => {
      agg += `  
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id="user${index}" name="user" value="">
            <label for="user${index}">${user}</label><br>
        </div>
        `
      return agg;
    }, ''),
    focusConfirm: false,
  })
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", test);
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.18.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="test" class="button">Click</button>




No problem. Actually the other answer is a bit more efficient because doing string+string is slower than array.join("")

If anyone else is interested and wants to try a different method, you can do so with the map array method.


const arr = ['Alex', 'Jasmine', 'Andrie', 'Elton', 'Susy'];

function test() {
  Swal.fire({
    html: arr.map(user => {
      return (
        `<div>
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="${user}">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">${user}</label>
        </div>`
      )
    }).join(""),
    focusConfirm: false,
  })
}

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", test);
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@7.18.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="test" class="button">Click</button>



Note that I used the join("") method because when I printed the various users the comma (the separator of the array elements) was also printed.

I took liberty to remove some whitespace and format a bit to make this great answer more visually clear.

@MarkSchultheiss You did a great job. Thanks. How do you format the code? Is there a quick tool to do this? Or do you do it line by line?

Two parts the tool has a format on the left but within the JS template I just removed the whitespace - technically HTML requires no whitespace so whitespace then becomes whatever is needed by the developer for visual clarity when developing; side note NO whitespace is better as "less to download", "less to parse" etc.

@MarkSchultheiss Perfect, thank you very much

Side note, html template https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template can be used OR the template literal as you used here ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals
